# Как взять предпоследнюю строку из массива String?

Tags: java

Как узнать предпоследнюю, предпредпоследнюю и т.д. строку массива String и инициализировать как int?

```
String[] lines = result.toString().split("\\n");
```

Comment: Вам не помог мой ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос?

Comment: Помог, спасибо большое! Но это же другой вопрос.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, его стоит [отметить решением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/204271). Вам это даст немного репутации, автору ответа мотив отвечать вам и дальше, а другим пользователям поможет найти ответ на такой же вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(lines[lines.length - 2]);
```